# Center span of h1 relative to parent

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

My goal is to be able to center the "Animal Wildlife" relative to the container while the span still stays on the left side .

```
<div class="container">
<h1><span>Subscribe to </span>Animal Wildlife</h1>
</div>
```

How can I center part of the h1 while keeping the structure?

Answer (score 0):

**center object**

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* center horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* center vertical */
}


/* --------------------------------- */

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container2 h1 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto; /* center both */
}


/* --------------------------------- */

.container3 {
  position: relative;
}

.container3 h1 {
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; /* center left */
  top: 50%; /* center top */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* center object */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container1">
    <h1><span>Subscribe to </span>Animal Wildlife</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container2">
    <h1><span>Subscribe to </span>Animal Wildlife</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container3">
    <h1><span>Subscribe to </span>Animal Wildlife</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: These solutions does not fix the problem. I basically want to change the center point of the h1 a little to the right. I want the "Subscribe to" to act like its not there when it comes to centering the h1. Thanks for helping though.